# Why doesn't this jquery code work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, click

I have this code in my application.js file, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#video_div img").click(function() {
   $("div.embed").toggle();
});
```

Here's the HTML my browser sees:

```
<div id="video_div">
<img src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/fTWpHknumdg/hqdefault.jpg" style="width: 200px; ">
<div class="embed">
<object width="300" height="194"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/fTWpHknumdg?version=3">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/fTWpHknumdg?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="194" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque">
</object>
</div>
</div>
```

Right now, I am hiding the `div.embed` element with `div.embed { display: none;}` but the click method isn't making the element reappear again...

Comment: Are you getting any errors from your browser?

Comment: Working for me, on Firefox: http://jsbin.com/ulicu5

Comment: Did you put the jQuery code in the ready function? ie. `$(function() { /* here */ });`

Comment: Are you sure the element isn't reappearing and the flash is not simply unloaded? Flash behaves in mysterious ways when it is hidden, especially with wmode=opaque

Answer (score 0):

Is your code getting called?  Do you need to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#video_div img").click(function() {
        $("div.embed").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. Are you sure you have jQuery loaded. Make sure your jquery.js is placed just before the closing body tag `</body>`

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Ey4YC/

You can also try your code like this if your want to keep your jquery.js in the header.

```
$(function() {
    $("#video_div img").click(function() {
        $("div.embed").toggle();
    });
```

Comment: here's the included js files in the <head></head>:
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js?1299978321" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.embedly.js?1299981574" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1299978356" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1300094470" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Don't put those in the head. Put them just before `</body>`

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/Ey4YC/2, this is exactly how your code should look like.

Comment: do you know ruby on rails? would you mind checking out my code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ruby. However ruby shouldn't be the problem. The example links i provided shows you the working example. If you feel it's a ruby issue, ask another question relating to that.

Comment: @justin The example and jsfiddle i provided are both valid answers to your questions consider accepting the answer to give credit where credit is due. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is Flash error. try the same code but this time when u click the image then resize browser.

recently my firefox and chrome oftenly not render youtube's vdo(the vdo just white like nothing load) but after i resize browser's window its appear.